# Shared methods split declared in header and defined in cpp file

Tags: c++, c++11, methods, automake

I'm working on writing a library and I'm using another library within it (linking it). I have some shared methods, one being 'compare' for example. When I declare and define this compare method in the header using

```
 bool Compare(std::string s1, std::string s2, bool ignoreCase)
```

and then in the .cpp file using

```
 bool Compare(std::string s1, std::string s2, 
 bool ignoreCase){...}
```

this .cpp file also includes the corresponding header file. However, when test my library I'm getting:

> `./main: symbol lookup error: /..path to .so file/libmylibrary.so.0: undefined symbol: _Z7CompareSsSsb` error.

I've tried declaring and defining within the header file using

```
inline bool Compare(std::string s1, std::string s2, bool ignoreCase){...}`,
```

which compiled and then worked fine when I tested it. I've also used make clean during automake a few times, but I still keep getting the same error.

Any tips or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like the shared object (so) file is missing at runtime. Or is at a different location. If the file is there, is the symbol being exported correctly? Gcc has the __attribute__(visibility...).

Comment: See here; https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility

Comment: Without seeing the Makefile.am that you're trying to use (since you tagged automake) it's very hard to figure out what you're trying to do.